# In App Purchase-Unlock Features

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Hi 
I am creating an inapp purchase iphone application. My application has build in model. It has a table view which has 6  items. In free app 3 items are available and I want to lock 3 items. People can unlock all three items by just making a single transaction of $0.99.

I want to create a plist file in my application which will contain a flag. If flag=0 then lock few features and if flag=1 then unlock everything. My plist will contain only one "flag" which may be 0 or 1.

I don't know how to create a plist file. Where should i keep a plist file so that customers couldn't access it? Should I keep it in resource folder?

After SKTransactionStatePurchased, I want to change the flag in .plist file. Can you please give me the code which will change flag value from 0 to 1 in flag.plist file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should look for another approach to solve your issue, for a couple of reasons:

- plists can be edited by ANYONE who has access to internal iOS filesystem: That includes jailbreakers and there are certain tools that allow non-jailbreakers to access it as well.
- Editing a plist with code requires permissions. Your app only has editing permissions in it's Documents folder. That said, someone could easily make a jailbreak app to access your app's document folder to edit it's value fairly easily.

My apologies for not directly answering your question, but storing that sort of things in the documents the app uses is really a bad idea. I highly recommend you to look for alternative methods to do this (like using your own server).

Comment: Well i am an individual not a company and I don't have servers or a website. I also don't want to pay for them. I know there are several other individual person who are creating in app purchase applications. What method is being used by them if they are not using plist method? What is a common approach of doing it?

Comment: I haver made an in-app purchase myself, but I know a couple of things; that people use their own server, and sometimes yeah, they make the "unlocking" in the app itself. I am not exactly sure about the last method though, because everything that can be engineered can be reverse engineered. I would look into using NSUserDefaults if I was you, but always using some sort of description.

Comment: (void)provideContent: (NSString *)productId
{
if ([productId isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId])
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased" ];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
}                                                                        If I use this code, does it mean that I am setting a flag "IsProUpgradePurchased" in NSUserDefaults which can not be accessed and changed by user who is making a purchase or by jailbreakers. DO I need a server to implement NSUserDefaults?

Comment: There's no need to have a server to use NSUserDefaults. That should do the trick just fine temporarily. The main issue is that it is not being encrypted in any way. What are you doing now is more secure than before, but only for users who are not jailbroken. You may consider to store certain tokens using the iOS Keychain as well.

Answer (score 2):

To actually answer your question:

After SKTransactionStatePurchased, just call

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"yourKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

yourKey can be anything of your own choice. Probably it is best
to use meaningless and random word for it so that hackers won't 
know that it is related to in app purchase.